# background color of uiactionsheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try to change the background color of my actionsheet, I just use the method:

[actionSheet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:30 green:30 blue:30 alpha:0.5]];

and I put it in the willPresentActionSheet. But the background color don't change, why?

Answer (score 12):

- add QuartzCore.framework
- set delegate for your actionsheet
- set style for actionsheet: UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent
- override method willPresentActionSheet

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
...

yourActionSheet.delegate = self;
yourActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
...

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
    [[actionSheet layer] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
}
```

Comment: This does not work when action sheet is presented from tab bar: [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar], but works when presented from view: [actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view].

Comment: + 1 for simple and short answer..:)

Comment: This changes just the background of the content.  It does not affect popover arrows or text color.   Informative though, thanks.