# How to set background color for UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiactionsheet

In the following method

`- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{`

I have set:

`[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

This is for one button.
But here is what I get:

[image]

What I want to know is how to set the color only on button without the side gaps ?

Any guidance or help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491197/how-to-change-color-of-uiactionsheet-in-ios-7

Comment: try [this](http://blog.corywiles.com/customizing-uiactionsheet-buttons)

Comment: You can see at here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426272/background-color-of-uiactionsheet
Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also need the custom UIAcionSheet but default actionsheet doesn't support the customization functionality so i used the other customer controller [UICustomActionSheet](https://github.com/gloomcore/UICustomActionSheet/tree/master/UICustomActionSheet(ARC)) and got the expected result like

[image]

Comment: Will this pass to store?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the title color use the below code.

```
for (UIView *view in actionSheet.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```